# Delete items, folders, and projects in Autodesk A360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I am working with A360 and creating a simple project which requires data management. Everything works well except the delete operation. When I am trying to use [PATCH projects/:project_id/items/:item_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/) endpoint, the server returns 200 Ok, but the item remains.

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "items",
    "id": "my_id",
    "attributes": {
        "hidden": true
    }
  }
}
```

I found such info in the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-PATCH/) for the folders - *You can only delete BIM 360 Docs folders*. 
So, as I understand, only BIM 360 entities can be deleted.

- Are there any workarounds to delete items in A360?
- Does Autodesk have any plans adding such functionality for A360?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, indeed as of today this feature is only for BIM 360.